# Import from down-cast variable in Scala?

Tags: scala, casting, import

I'm writing a ScalaTest JMock expectation. The syntax is usually

```
expecting { e => import e._
  // call methods on e
}
```

Now I happen to know that e is a subclass of Expectation. I can write

```
expecting { e => 
  val e2 = e.asInstanceOf[MySubclass]
  import e2._
  // call MySubclass methods
}
```

but I can't find any way of making a one-liner like

```
expecting { e => import (e.asInstanceOf[MySubclass])._
  // call MySubclass methods
}
```

compile.

Is there anyway to combine down-casting and importing in a single step?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don´t see a way to combine both, but I would rather implement it like this:

```
expecting { case e: MySubclass => import e._
  ...
}
```

Comment: Sweet - is there a problem in Scala which isn't solved by adding a case statement?

Comment: @Duncan `case` is everywhere :D